# Cloudant search index response without one index field

Tags: search, indexing, lucene, cloudant

I have a json document example:

```
{
  "_id": "1000001101012017",
  "_rev": "1-b7de1e91dbcac1ca098be7d99ddea138",
  "ACC_ID": 1005,
  "DT": 201701010000000000,
  "DBO": 0.9,
  "CRO": 0,
  "SALDO": -2.05
}
```

and the Search index function:

```
function (doc) {
  index("saldoSearch", doc._id);
  if(doc.DT){
    index("DT", doc.DT, {"store":true})
  }
  if(doc.ACC_ID){
    index("ACC_ID", doc.ACC_ID, {"store":true})
  }
  if(doc.SALDO){
    index("SALDO", doc.SALDO, {"store":true})
  }
}
```

search query is:

```
{
  "q": "ACC_ID: 1005 AND DT: [198905260000000000 TO 201702241046285215]",
  "sort": "-DT",
  "limit": 1
}
```

and response:

```
{
  "total_rows": 4,
  "bookmark": "g1AAAABReJzLYWBgYMxgTmGQS87JL01JzCtxKCkugbFTkoz1Mgr1SpKSc4DqmPJYGFYBAZD6DwRZYDE357aU7W4tTgpJDKvUqrKyACwGG7U",
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": "100502012017",
      "order": [
        201702010000000000,
        11150970
      ],
      "fields": {
        "DT": 201702010000000000,
        "ACC_ID": 1005
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

response is without "SALDO" field but when 
`"q":"ACC_ID: 1005 AND DT: [198905260000000000 TO 201702241046285215] AND SALDO: [-identity TO identity]"`
response is result with "SALDO" but waithing ~10 second.

How can I get a response with "SALDO" and be high performanse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve you problem is to use add `include_docs=true` to your query string i.e.

```
{
  "q": "ACC_ID: 1005 AND DT: [198905260000000000 TO 201702241046285215]",
  "sort": "-DT",
  "limit": 1,
  "include_docs": true
}
```

The search results will then contain the entire document in the result object.

Comment: Thank you very much